# Is there a way to control the NSMenuItem item that is initially highlighted when opening a menu?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmenu

I'm working on the details of a symbols pop up button, similar to what Xcode 3 at the top of its editor window.

My controller object is the delegate of the `NSMenu` that is shown when the `NSPopUpButton` is shown. I implement the two methods `numberOfItemsInMenu:` and `menu:updateItem:atIndex:shouldCancel:` to populate the menu right before it's about to be displayed.

However, the title and image of the selected `NSMenuItem` have to change each time the user changes the selection in the editor `NSTextView`, or makes changes to the text; just as is the case with Xcode.

The problem I'm having is when the user goes to click on the `NSPopUpButton` to display the `NSMenu`, the selected `NSMenuItem` and the item that should be selected do not match up, since the menu doesn't have the proper number of items yet.

I'm wondering if there is a way to control which `NSMenuItem` is initially highlighted and tracked when the user clicks to open the menu. As it stands, the first item it always highlighted and tracked or, if the user had previously selected a item, that item is highlighted and tracked.

I tried explaining as best I could, but here is a image illustrating my problem:

[image: http://imgur.com/izGvh]

I want the highlighted item to be the same as the selected item when the user opens the menu. Any ideas?

Comment: The reason why the selected item is initially "tracked" is that it's directly under the mouse pointer, so that if you just open the menu and close it again, the selection won't change. If you want to change this behaviour, you'll have to subclass NSPopUpButton.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a NSPopupbutton - it can do what you want. maybe you even hide it?

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure that I understood your problem but If we can add tags to these menu Items.
e.g.

```
[mMenuItemOne setTag : 1];
[mMenuItemTwo setTag : 2];
[mMenuItemThree setTag : 3];
[mMenuItemFour setTag : 4];}
```

we can select any Menu item using
    [_popUp selectItemWithTag: _selectedItem];

Comment: You can set these tags directly in Interface Builder, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this `NSMenuDelegate` method:*Handling Highlighting*

```
– menu:willHighlightItem:
```

[NSMenuDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSMenuDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Also you can store the `NSMenuItem` index in some var to keep track of the selected item for later use.

Comment: this method does not allow you to change which item will be highlighted, so it would not apply in my particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint not a full solution.

Try to post an NSMouseMoved event to your app right after the menu shown.
Main problem is here to detect the position of the item you want to be highlighted.
Just a starting point.

Comment: might even work but sounds hakisch -- and you'd need carbon to get the frames IIRC

Comment: *never* move the mouse. Nor try to fake the app to think the mouse is in a different location than it is. It breaks the association that "the mouse is an extension of my hand" and confuses the hell out of users.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, do you want to move the mouse selection highlight (the blue stuff) or the checkmark?

In general, the checkmark is the thing you want to change. You can do so from your `validateMenuItem:` method (or at any other time if your item is set not to take part in validation) using the `-setState:` method.

The blue highlight is an indicator of the user's keyboard input or mouse location, and you should not mess with it. Changing it does not make any sense, as it would be changed back the moment the user moves the mouse even a single pixel.

That said, you *can* set the `selectedItem` of the `NSPopUpButton`, which will cause the entire menu to be moved so the `selectedItem` is under the mouse (assuming the mouse just clicked the popup button).

If your menu delegate method is called after the pop up button has decided what item to select, you can't use it. Instead, you could probably set the `selectedItem` and menu of the popup button from a `NSPopUpButtonWillPopUpNotification` handler.

If that is also called too late, you'll probably have to subclass `NSPopupButtonCell` and do it in an override of `-attachPopUpWithFrame:inView:` (I think that's the spot that should also work when you don't click and just hit the space key while the popup button is selected).